# Order and degree of an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation

$$\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x} = \log x.$$

Obviously, its degree is $1$ and order is $1$. However, if we apply antilog on the differential equation, we get

$$\exp \left(\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x} \right) = x,$$

then its degree is undefined and order is $1$.

I am a bit confused as to why the degree gets changed while the differential equation is the same.

Comment: Thank you Rodrigo for editing the question

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the order of the first ODE you wrote is equal to 1, but why do you think that its degree ought to be 1?

Could you please post your definition for the degree? I'd assume that the notion of a degree is only well-defined for ODEs that are composed of (finitely many) polynomial expressions, which clearly is not the case in your example.

I'd rather say that the degree is not well-defined in your case, which is backed by the result you obtained from your transformation.